# Error while creating a new scrapy project using anaconda prompt

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

After installing scrapy in the anaconda command prompt using this command line :

[image: Command line]

The installation process succeeds.
Then I tried to create a new scrapy project but I had this Error message :

[image: Error while creating a new project]

Did you have any idea about the way to solve this issue ? 
I'm using Anaconda 2 under Windows 10

Comment: Please for code, error : text, paste it don't put a picture ;)

Comment: Please read [MCVE]